# How can I convert a SQL statement with cursor to set based?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL statement with the following cursors:

```
declare @sId uniqueidentifier 
declare @aId uniqueidentifier 
declare @cId uniqueidentifier 
declare @iId uniqueidentifier 
declare @lDate datetime

declare test_cursor cursor for 
     select jb.actId, js.smId, jb.CustId, jb.Id, jb.DateTime 
     from Job jb
     left join SM js on js.keyvalue = jb.Id
     where jb.DateTime < DATEADD(month, -12, getdate())

open test_cursor
fetch next from test_cursor into @Id, @sId, @cId, @iId, @lDate

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    delete from Logs 
    where actId = @aId

    update SM 
    set Status = 88 
    where smId = @sId

    insert into LAC 
    values (NEWID(), @cId, @iId, @lDate, getdate())

    fetch next from test_cursor into @aId, @sId, @cId, @iId, @lDate
end

close test_cursor
deallocate test_cursor
```

How can I change this to use set based, as it would be quicker?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: im using sql ..

Comment: SQL is a language, supported by many products. (Seems like someone recognized MS SQL Server code here.)

Comment: Where is `@Id` coming from? Where is the initial value assigned to `@aId`, i.e. before the first `delete`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines would likely go faster.

```
    delete from Logs where actId =@aId;
    
    update SM set Status = 88 where smId in(
    js.smId from Job jb
            left join SM js on js.keyvalue = jb.Id
            where jb.DateTime < DATEADD(month, -12, getdate());
    
    insert into LAC (a,b,c,d,e)
    select newID(),jb.Id, jb.CustId, @lDate , getdate() from Job jb
            left join SM js on js.keyvalue = jb.Id
            where jb.DateTime < DATEADD(month, -12, getdate());
```

You can do your initial select into a temp table and use that if you're worried about consistency or performance.

Comment: I dont quite get this .. what is the a,b,c,d,e , the values are retrieved from the cursor fetch ?

Comment: They are the columns in LAC that you insert the select from.  If you don't name them you can just align your select with the columns as you did with your insert/values clause.

Comment: sorry I cant see how it works . They look like  4 separate statements,not linked in any way. Also @aId is a value retrieved from the table select ..I cant see how it works by traversing the results of the select

Comment: Ive traced it through in ssms and now get what you mean didnt understand at first